# What is the proper way to call MobileAds.initialize()?

Tags: android

From the [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds):

> This method should be called as early as possible, and only once per
>   application launch.

I thought of calling this method from the `Application` class of my app the following way:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), myAppId);
    }
}
```

Is this considered good practice in this case?

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: This adds a cool 500ms to my app startup time... Google, please!!!

Comment: @Maarten Adding 'OPTIMIZE_INITIALIZATION' meta-data may improve the loading time, I seem new api of Google from admob 21.0.0 https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/optimize-initialization

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes this should be fine, and Google actually recommends doing it this way for other packages. For example, in Google's [setup guide for Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#application), they recommend initializing the global `GoogleAnalytics` object inside an `Application` subclass.

So yes, this is a proper way to initialize `MobileAds`.

Comment: I had always left out 'MobileAds.initialize' because I had seen a docs page saying it was depreciated, even though other docs pages were still using it. This doc page: developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/rel-no‌​tes for dfp (doubleclick) publishers says it is 'undepreciated' and suggests admob publishers use it '9.8.0 2016‑10‑24 MobileAds.Initialize(Context) has been un-deprecated. DFP and Ad Exchange publishers should call this method when initializing their apps. AdMob publishers should still use MobileAds.Initialize(Context, String) and pass their application code'

Comment: Google guys are wrong in this case, I have this code line in production right now and it is causing ANR on some devices.

Comment: After we have initialised `MobileAds` in `Application` subclass, do we need to call it in our activities? Referring to Google Analytic link which you share, they call `AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication(); mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();` in activity.

Comment: This method has been deprecated.

Comment: Do we need this initialization, If we are only using dfp ads not admob

Comment: SDK team are checking ANR when init MobileAds in onCreate until now https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/QFEoEJUbXjk

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code looks perfect. Some google examples recommend to use Activity.onCreate, but that contradicts to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds):

> "This method should be called as early as possible, and only once per
>   application launch".

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/91AxN2Q9Znk) explains why you should call initialize. Shortly: it speeds up first call AdView.loadAd. At the same time I noticed that it slows down application creation.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `MobileAds.initialize()` is optional and `MobileAds.initialize()` executes on `Main Thread`. So calling it in the `onCreate` of the `Activity` will create a lag in the display of your `Activity`.

I tested it on OnePlus 6 and execution of `MobileAds.initialize()` is taking **400-500 ms**.

My Implementation is to call `MobileAds.initialize()` in a Separate `Thread` created in the `onCreate` method of the `Application` Instance.

```
public class CustomApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MobileAds.initialize(context, initializationStatus -> {
                    Logger.log("MobileAds init");
                });
                //Other heavy task
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any doc link which says it is optional

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/MobileAds#initialize(android.content.Context,%20com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener)

Comment: It says:

Call this method as early as possible after the app launches to reduce latency on the session's first ad request.

If this method is not called, the first ad request automatically initializes the Google Mobile Ads SDK.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/QFEoEJUbXjk/m/AMpZRiMMAwAJ